# Subversion: Locked or unlocked?

Tags: svn

I just pulled an SVN repo, freshly. Immediately after pulling, I `cd` into the folder and do an `svn status`. All files within the repo are locked. I then attempt to do a `svn unlock *`, yet I then get a message that nothing is locked in the current working copy. Very confused, these seem contradictory. How can I unlock the fricken files / folders?

Comment: You wrote you have svn status but did you try svn status -u ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also try a `svn cleanup` worked for me a few times in the past

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using svn unlock command with the force flag?

```
svn unlock -force *
```